# How can I keep receive HTTP POST data w/o sending WebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm new to ASP.NET. I have a router periodically sending HTTP POST JSON data (every one min)to Internet (my url, I have static IP) and I want to build a ASP.NET web or app to receive the data w/o sending WebRequest to the router.

I successfully received the data by building a node.js server on cloud server. (Like this one https://github.com/wzm90/UVGServer/blob/master/server.js) I want to know how to build a ASP.NET program to achieve the same goal.

I do the research and find that people receive HTTP POST data by send the request first, then call request.getResponce() function to get the data. But my situation is that I don't want to keep sending request. Since the router periodically send out data, I just want to persistently listen on a specific port, and get the data. How can I do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand.  If the router is the thing making the POST, why would your server have to make a request at all?  Wouldn't you just create a `HttpListener` and point the router at it?

Comment: @Joe That is what I want! I didn't find it before. Can you provide more about how to use HttpListener?

Comment: It's been a few years.  Something like this will show you the (very basic) basics: http://simoncropp.com/simpleclientandserverwithhttplistener

Comment: @Joe Thanks a lot. I have a question about listener.Prefixes.Add. Since I have a static IP, should I put localhost there or put my IP there? I tried both way in ASP.NET but I got server error when I tried to view the website.

Comment: I'd probably go 0.0.0.0 to listen on all available.